# Is there a way to use UdpClient with SOCKS proxy in c#/.net, or do a udp communication over socks?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, socks

I need to be able to use socks proxy to send/receive udp packets, and I can't find a native way to do it in .net 4 .

Is that true and there is no implementation in native .net framework ? , is there an additional library/class/function that would allow me to do this ?

Comment: .NET has no built in proxy support outside of its HTTP implementation.

Comment: There is no such thing as "UDP connection". And SOCKS 4 doesn't support UDP binding, only SOCKS 5 does. And no, there is no native support for SOCKS in .NET, and I think I even know why.